# How do I categorise the merge in R, using Stata?

Tags: r, merge, stata

I'm a Stata user and used to merge categorisation, with `_merge` taking values from 1 to 5. This is the code I have used:

```
locationcheck<-merge(location,pincodes,by="pincode",all.x=TRUE)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by categorize the merge ? Checkout that tuto : https://stat545-ubc.github.io/bit001_dplyr-cheatsheet.html

Comment: You would be much clearer to R users if you explained what `_merge` reports. It's documented at http://www.stata.com/manuals14/dmerge.pdf but you should put the explanation here. Otherwise you are just aiming at a small group people highly fluent in both Stata and R.

Comment: For _merge reference: 1: observation appeared in master (left table) only
2: observation appeared in using (right table) only
3: observation appeared in both
4: update observation appeared in both, missing values updated
5: conflict observation appeared in both, conflicting nonmissing
 from http://www.stata.com/manuals13/dmerge.pdf

Answer (score 1):

**[Asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358401/is-there-a-way-to-create-statas-merge-indicator-variable-with-rs-merge)** and **[answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30358639/4895877)**.

Per the answer linked above:

```
merge(x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y)),by.x = by, by.y = by, all = TRUE)
merge(x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y)),by.x = by, by.y = by, all.x = TRUE)
merge(x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y)),by.x = by, by.y = by, all.y = TRUE)
```

Additionally, the user who asked the question linked above [created a function to generate this variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30419255/4895877) (not being an R user, I have not tested this):

```
stata.merge <- function(x,y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y))){

x[is.na(x)] <- Inf
y[is.na(y)] <- Inf

matched <- merge(x, y, by.x = by, by.y = by, all = TRUE)
matched <- matched[complete.cases(matched),]
matched$merge <- "matched"
master <- merge(x, y, by.x = by, by.y = by, all.x = TRUE)
master <- master[!complete.cases(master),]
master$merge <- "master"
using <- merge(x, y, by.x = by, by.y = by, all.y = TRUE)
using <- using[!complete.cases(using),]
using$merge <- "using"

df <- rbind(matched, master,using)
df[sapply(df, is.infinite)] <- NA
df
}
```

Importantly, while I recall seeing this question, it was easy to find via a search of `[stata] [r] merge`.