# Is there a _merge indicator available after a merge?

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to get the equivalent of a `_merge` indicator variable after a merge in `dplyr`?

Something similar to **Pandas'** `indicator = True` option that essentially tells you how the merge went (how many matches from each dataset, etc).

Here is an example in `Pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key1' : ['a','b','c'], 'v1' : [1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key1' : ['a','b','d'], 'v2' : [4,5,6]})

match = df1.merge(df2, how = 'left', indicator = True)
```

Here, after a `left join` between `df1` and `df2`, you want to immediately know how many rows in `df1` found a match in `df2` and how many of them did not

```
match
Out[53]: 
  key1  v1   v2     _merge
0    a   1  4.0       both
1    b   2  5.0       both
2    c   3  NaN  left_only
```

and I can tabulate this `merge` variable:

```
match._merge.value_counts()
Out[52]: 
both          2
left_only     1
right_only    0
Name: _merge, dtype: int64
```

I don't see any option available after a, say, left join in `dplyr`

```
key1 = c('a','b','c')
v1 = c(1,2,3)
key2 = c('a','b','d')
v2 = c(4,5,6)
df1 = data.frame(key1,v1)
df2 = data.frame(key2,v2)

> left_join(df1,df2, by = c('key1' = 'key2'))
  key1 v1 v2
1    a  1  4
2    b  2  5
3    c  3 NA
```

Am I missing something here?
Thanks!

Comment: I guess you can create an indicator variable in 'x' and 'y' i.e. `x$merge <- 1; y$merge; left_join(x,y, by = "key")` if I understand the problem.

Comment: with a left join you wouldn't expect to see any right only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create the 'merge' column based on `inner_join`, `anti_join` and then bind the rows with `bind_rows`

```
d1 <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = c('key1' = 'key2')) %>%
                    mutate(merge = "both")  
bind_rows(d1, anti_join(df1, df2, by = c('key1' = 'key2')) %>% 
             mutate(merge = 'left_only'))
```

Comment: thanks that great but I believe this should be included as an option. thanks!

Comment: @Noobie You can raise a feature request in dplyr to include that in the next release

Answer (score 8):

Stata similarly creates a new variable `_merge` when doing any type of merge or join. I too find it helpful to have as an option in order to diagnose a merge quickly after performing it.

For the last few months I've been using basic functions I wrote that simply embellish the `dplyr` joins. There are probably more efficient ways of doing this, but here is an example of one that embellishes `full_join`. If you set the option `.merge = T` you'll get a variable, called `.merge` that is similar to _merge in **Stata** or **Pandas**. (This also just prints off a diagnostic message about how many cases matched and didn't match each time you use it.) I know you already have an answer to the question, but if you want a function you can use repeatedly that works identically to `full_join` in `dplyr`, here is a start. You obviously need dplyr loaded to make this work...

```
full_join_track <- function(x, y, by = NULL, suffix = c(".x", ".y"),
                        .merge = FALSE, ...){

# Checking to make sure used variable names are not already in use
if(".x_tracker" %in% names(x)){
    message("Warning: variable .x_tracker in left data was dropped")
}
if(".y_tracker" %in% names(y)){
    message("Warning: variable .y_tracker in right data was dropped")
}
if(.merge & (".merge" %in% names(x) | ".merge" %in% names(y))){
    stop("Variable .merge already exists; change name before proceeding")
}

# Adding simple merge tracker variables to data frames
x[, ".x_tracker"] <- 1
y[, ".y_tracker"] <- 1

# Doing full join
joined <- full_join(x, y, by = by, suffix = suffix,  ...)

# Calculating merge diagnoses 
matched <- joined %>%
    filter(!is.na(.x_tracker) & !is.na(.y_tracker)) %>%
    NROW()
unmatched_x <- joined %>%
    filter(!is.na(.x_tracker) & is.na(.y_tracker)) %>%
    NROW()
unmatched_y <- joined %>%
    filter(is.na(.x_tracker) & !is.na(.y_tracker)) %>%
    NROW()

# Print merge diagnoses
message(
    unmatched_x, " Rows ONLY from left data frame", "\n",
    unmatched_y, " Rows ONLY from right data frame", "\n",
    matched, " Rows matched"
)

# Create .merge variable if specified
if(.merge){
    joined <- joined %>%
        mutate(.merge = 
                   case_when(
                       !is.na(.$.x_tracker) & is.na(.$.y_tracker) ~ "left_only",
                       is.na(.$.x_tracker) & !is.na(.$.y_tracker) ~ "right_only",
                       TRUE ~ "matched"
                       )
               )
}

# Dropping tracker variables and returning data frame
joined <- joined %>%
    select(-.x_tracker, -.y_tracker)
return(joined)
}
```

As an example:

```
data1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10))
data2 <- data.frame(x = 4:20, z = rnorm(17))
full_join_track(data1, data2, .merge = T)
```

Comment: This is pretty great. Thanks!

Comment: @mmann1123. I actually put this function and a couple others into a package called **reviewr** that you can access on my [github page](https://github.com/adamMaier/reviewr). It has some more functionality than the function above (it's called full_join_qc) there and the package contains other functions that print off diagnostics that I find helpful. For example, a function called `filter_qc` prints the number of rows dropped when performing a filter; `mutate_qc` prints the number of NAs created when making a new variable.

Comment: If you download the whole package you can access the vignette I wrote that shows how to use these functions. And each function has help documentation. In short, they all work identically to their `dplyr` counterparts but print more diagnostic information and in some cases create new variables for you like the equivalent of Stata's _merge.  To download the package, use `devtools::install_github("adamMaier/reviewr", build_vignettes = T)`. Once you do that you can add te package to your library like any others: `library(reviewr)`