# A merge indicator for R data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

My question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110644/is-there-a-merge-indicator-available-after-a-merge) but it was asking `dplyr` solution.

What I'd like to do is to perform outer join and create a indicator variable that explains the merge result, like `pandas` or `STATA` would do.

To be specific, I would like to have `_merge` column after full outer join operation that indicates the merge result with left_only or right_only or both as below example.

UPDATE : I've updated example

```r
key1 = c('a','b','c','d','e')
v1 = c(1,2,3, NA, 5)
key2 = c('a','b','d','f')
v2 = c(4,5,6,7)
df1 = data.frame(key=key1,v1)
df2 = data.frame(key=key2,v2)

> df1
   key v1
1:   a  1
2:   b  2
3:   c  3
4:   d NA
5:   e  5

> df2
   key v2
1:   a  4
2:   b  5
3:   d  6
4:   f  7

# merge result I'd like to have

   key v1 v2     _merge
1:   a  1  4       both
2:   b  2  5       both
3:   c  3 NA  left_only
4:   d NA  6       both # <- not right_only, both
5:   e  5 NA  left_only
6:   f NA  7 right_only
```

I'm wondering if I'm missing an existing `data.table` feature, or is there a simple way to do this task?

Comment: Your code is written in `python`.  Do you want `R` solution or python

Comment: Perhaps `df2[df1, on = .(key1)][, `_merge` := fcase(is.na(v2), 'left_only', 'both')]`

Comment: or with `fifelse` `df2[df1, on = .(key1)][, `_merge` := fifelse(is.na(v2), 'left_only', 'both')][]`

Comment: @akrun As far as I know, using `[` for join only performs one-side. Won't `df2[df1, on=.(key1)]` drop unmatched rows in df2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `merge.data.table` with `all=TRUE` for a full outer join:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
DT <- merge(df1[, r1 := .I], df2[, r2 := .I], by="key", all=TRUE)
DT[, merge_ := "both"][
    is.na(r1), merge_ := "right_only"][
        is.na(r2), merge_ := "left_only"]
```

output:

```
   key v1 r1 v2 r2     merge_
1:   a  1  1  4  1       both
2:   b  2  2  5  2       both
3:   c  3  3 NA NA  left_only
4:   d NA NA  6  3 right_only
```

data:

```
key1 = c('a','b','c')
v1 = c(1,2,3)
key2 = c('a','b','d')
v2 = c(4,5,6)
df1 = data.frame(key=key1,v1)
df2 = data.frame(key=key2,v2)
```

---

As mentioned by Michael Chirico, with `data.table_1.13.0` released on Jul 24, 2020, one can also use `fcase` as follows:

```
DT[, merge_ := fcase(
    is.na(r1), "right_only",
    is.na(r2), "left_only",
    default = "both"
)]
```

Comment: proviso is that we must choose `v1` and `v2` that are `!anyNA` before the merge. Might also be worth mentioning a solution with `fcase` relevant to the dev version of `data.table`

Comment: @MichaelChirico agreed, so we will have to create some dummy columns x1 and x2 in df1 and df2 to handle possible NAs in v1 and v2. I do not have access to github.com from here and hence i can only post based on CRAN. Please feel free to add a solution and i am happy to delete

Comment: @MichaelChirico Why the need to generate r1/2 via `.I`? Wouldn´t `is.na(v1 or 2)'`be sufficient?

Comment: @Misha the original data might contain NAs.